# Unbound Module when using Dream eml pre-processor

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm trying to learn OCaml by way of building a website with this lovely library I found called Dream (https://aantron.github.io/dream/), but I've run into an issue when trying to work with the template preprocessor! My code
is copied straight from the `7-template` example from the library's github page, and everything seems to work, up until the point I run `dune build`. The preprocessor, `dream_eml`, converts my templated code with `jsx` style html markup to less pretty, but more compilable, OCaml code, but when it does, it inserts a reference to the module `Dream_pure`, and my compiler is saying that `Dream_pure` is an unbound module! Below you can find the preprocessed code as well as my `dune` file!

dune file:

```
(executable
 (name jenr_dev_server)
 (libraries base core dream)
 (preprocess (pps lwt_ppx)))

(rule
 (targets jenr_dev_server.ml)
 (deps jenr_dev_server.eml.ml)
 (action (run dream_eml %{workspace_root}/src/server/%{deps})))
```

expanded code:

```
#1 "./src/server/jenr_dev_server.eml.ml"
let render param =
let ___eml_buffer = Buffer.create 4096 in
(Buffer.add_string ___eml_buffer "<html>\n<body>\n  <h1>The URL parameter was ");
(Printf.bprintf ___eml_buffer "%s" (Dream_pure.Formats.html_escape (
#4 "./src/server/jenr_dev_server.eml.ml"
                                  param 
)));
(Buffer.add_string ___eml_buffer "!</h1>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n");
(Buffer.contents ___eml_buffer)
#8 "./src/server/jenr_dev_server.eml.ml"
let () =
  Dream.run
  @@ Dream.logger
  @@ Dream.router [

    Dream.get "/:word"
      (fun request ->
        Dream.param request "word"
        |> render
        |> Dream.html);

  ]
```

the error message

```
File "../../src/server/jenr_dev_server.eml.ml", line 4, characters 36-66:
Error: Unbound module Dream_pure
```

I tried reinstalling the library on my `opam` switch with `opam install dream` as well as reconfiguring the `dune` file to match the example from the library's repository

Comment: What does your `dune_project` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you've disabled `implicit_transitive_deps` in your `dune_project` file. As [the documentation states](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#implicit-transitive-deps):

> Then all dependencies directly used by a library or an executable must be added in the `libraries` field.

Which means you'll have to add `dream-pure` to `libraries` in your `dune` file.

It seems it could also be fixed in dream by adding `re_export` to `dream-pure` in its `libraries` stanza.